# Which one is better for low latency java applications? Spring boot or just spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am planning to create a low latency web backend application using java. I am thinking to use spring boot(probably latest version) for this since it give many features developer ready like JPA, spring-data-mongodb starter packs etc. However i am not sure if it causes issues wrt latency. Does writing a backend java application using spring boot actually affect my application latency against writing the same using spring framework(not spring boot). If you have any links with analysis please do share it.

Also what capabilities do i lose if i choose to write code using spring boot

Comment: No, it doesn't. In the end, it's Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux that handles your requests.

Comment: Does it become an overhead for latency with many starter packs included in application?

Comment: You add a starter to help you autoconfigure something you need. If you need it and use Spring, you'll have to configure it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [Introducing Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-introducing-spring-boot) documentation says:

> Spring Boot makes it **easy** to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring-based Applications that you can run. We take an opinionated view of the Spring platform and third-party libraries, so that you can **get started with minimum fuss**. Most Spring Boot applications need very little Spring configuration.

That's really all Spring Boot is: It makes it easy to start new Spring Framework projects, by automatically including the appropriate dependencies, and setting up and configuring Spring features in a "good" default way, that should work for most people.

Since Spring Boot will fill in the blanks, it may slow down the startup process, but not by much, and once the Spring application has started, there is no difference vs a manually set up Spring Framework application.